# Subcategories in grid but skip one level

Tags: magento-1.7, category, category-tree

I would like to place my subcategories in a category page and I found many examples how to do this. The only problem I have is that I use an extra category that I would like to skip.

So what I have:

```
Home --> Category --> Extra Category --> Subcategories
```

I would like to show the show the *Subcategories* on the *Category* page.

Is there a way I can do this? I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Try to do rewrite class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation`

And copy function `_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml`, where paste conditions:

```
if ($level!=2) {
    $html[] = ...
    $html[] = ...
    $html[] = ...
}
```

but not to change:

```
$html[] = $htmlChildren;
```